# Data not passing between components using Service

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to pass values from one Components to another but my code not working. Values on next page showing `undefined`.

This is my service class `UtilityService.ts`

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable
({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UtilityService {
  constructor() { }

  private message:string;

  public setMessage(message):void{

      this.message=message;
  }

  public readMessage():string {

      return this.message;
  }
}
```

This is my first component code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilityService } from '../UtilityService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css'],
  providers: [UtilityService]
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  private service;

  constructor(private employeeService: ProductService,utilityService: UtilityService) {

    this.service=utilityService;
    this.sendMessage();
  }

  private sendMessage():void {
    this.service.setMessage("h r u");
  }
}
```

This is my Second Component code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { UtilityService } from '../UtilityService';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-device-list',
  templateUrl: './device-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-list.component.css'],
  providers: [UtilityService]
})

export class DeviceListComponent implements OnInit {

  private service;
  private message:string;

  constructor(
    utilityService: UtilityService,
    private restApi: ProductService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ){

    this.service=utilityService;
    this.readMessage();
  }

  private readMessage():void {
       this.message=this.service.readMessage();
       console.log("service msg: "+this.message);
    }
}
```

I have followed [this](https://codippa.com/passing-data-from-parent-to-child-component-in-angular/) article. In `console.log` message showing `undefined`

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: @AdritaSharma -  I have never used stackbiltz. I am new to Angular

Comment: don't assign `utilityService to this.service`. you can use it without assign. `this.utilityService.setMessage('h r u');`

Comment: @ArvindChourasiya make sure that you are not adding UtilityService in any modules, if you do it that will create a new a new instance and will not be singleton

Comment: Have you checked whether DeviceListComponent calls readMessage *before* ProductsComponent calls sendMessage?

Comment: Follow this article for understanding sharing data between components: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/#Child-to-Parent-Sharing-Data-via-Output-and-EventEmitter

Comment: @FatehMohamed - Thanks for your input. New instances was getting created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have provided your service in the  level of components.It means that each of your components have a different instance of **UtilityService** service.You should provide your service in the  module that has included your components to its **declarations** array.

An example code:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
     ],
  declarations: [DeviceListComponent,ProductsComponent 
  ],

  providers: [UtilityService],
})
export class ProductModule {}
```

Comment: He defined UtilityService with `providedIn: 'root'`. If that was the goal then deleting definition `providers: [UtilityService]` from components will be enough

Comment: It's true. But it's better to don't overuse it. If your service is not going to be used by other components in application , it's better to limit it's scope.

Comment: Yes you sad it right, thanks. But we don't know purpose of his UtilityService at all...

Answer (score 4):

You need to remove:   `providers: [UtilityService]` from `ProductsComponent` and from `DeviceListComponent` as it creates a new instance of `UtilityService` instead of using a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You defined your service with `providedIn: 'root'`, which means that instance of service will exists in whole context of application. If was that your goal just delete `providers: [UtilityService]` definition from `DeviceListComponent` and `ProductsComponent`, then it will be okey and works.

But I recommend you to read official documentation about **Angular providers** from official [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/providers). There is explanation about `providedIn: 'root'`, and other ways how to provide Angular service.

I have to mention guide about [Angular Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction), here you can learn different ways how to pass data between components.

Answer (score 0):

Use `BehaviourSubject` in `UtilityService`.

```
msgSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
currentMsg = this.msgSource.asObservable();
```

In `firstComponent` to `setMessage` use `BehaviourSubject's next()`

```
this.service.msgSource.next("Your message");
```

In `secondComponent` subscribe to `currentMsg`

```
this.service.currentMsg.subscribe(msg=> {
  //TODO
}
```

Comment: I don't think he is using Subjects or Observables. He's just setting data in one component and getting it in another.

Comment: It's good advice to use Rxjs, but this answer not solve guys problem. And his problem is about how he is providing his service